# decode a 14-digit timestamp

Tags: datetime, timestamp

I am running an API to get a report of events in bold360, the timestamps appear as 14-digits. example:

63778373872914 = 21/01/2022
63778307664492 = 20/01/2022

I discarded **UNIX** and **ISO** formats so far, Any idea of the timestamp format, I am using python to process the data and the [bold360 documentation](https://developer.bold360.com/help/EN/Bold360API/Bold360ai_API_SDK/External_Files/API_Ref/apiref.html) is not very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](https://developer.bold360.com/help/EN/Bold360API/Bold360ai_API_SDK/External_Files/API_Ref/apiref.html) are pretty clear:

> [...] REST API call returns a time value in .NET milliseconds [...]

So I'd assume those are milliseconds since 0001-01-01. Python example - because I can hack that together most quickly; should work in any language with datetime / duration support:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# 63778373872914 = 21/01/2022
print(datetime(1,1,1)+timedelta(milliseconds=63778373872914))
# 2022-01-21 14:57:52.914000

# 63778307664492 = 20/01/2022
print(datetime(1,1,1)+timedelta(milliseconds=63778307664492))
# 2022-01-20 20:34:24.492000
```

Comment: example for another language: [go](https://go.dev/play/p/haoLi-DzV_i)

Answer (score 1):

If you paste this "63778373872914" into an online timestamp converter, you either get a date in the future (Sunday, 2023026-03-19 12:41:54 UTC) or an invalid response on some other websites.

So I guess that something is wrong with the timestamp you got, maybe try changing it.

Comment: Well, the situation is that the API is sending me that data but I read the whole reference and I cannot find the encode that they are using for their timestamps.

Comment: Can you say which api you are using?

Comment: Reports - Get (get) GET http://{{account}}.nanorep.co/api/report/v1/get